Quanteda overlap frequency reporting problem
I’m hoping to identify an apparent miscalculation due to overlapping terms.
In the dummy data set and code below, which uses the same code on the actual data, the analysis works as expected. “Australia” is identified as occurring twice and “Australia Post” once.
library (quanteda)

txt <- c(doc1 = "There are a lot of dairy farms in Australia.",
         doc2 = "Dairy comprise a significant percent of all farms in Australia.",
         doc3 = "Not all farms are dairy farms, in fact, most  farms are not.",
         doc4 = "Some are lucky to receive a service from Australia Post.")

x <- tokens(txt, remove_punct = TRUE)

x1 <- dfm(x)
t1 <- textstat_frequency(x1)
t1

dict  <- dictionary(list(dairy = c("dairy", "dairy farms","dairy farm","milk"),
                         auspost = "australia post",
                         aus = c("australia", "this country", "our country"),
                         farmers = c("farmers", "farmer", "farm", "farms")))

kwicdict <- kwic(x, pattern = dict, window = 3)
kwicdict 

##Count dictionary key 
dfm1 <- dfm(tokens_lookup(x, dictionary = dict))
d1  <- convert(dfm1, to = "data.frame")
d1

## Count phrases (e.g. phrases that comprise the key)
dfm2 <- dfm(tokens_compound(x, dict)) %>% 
  dfm_select(dict)

dat22 <- convert(dfm2, to = "data.frame")
head(dat22)

However, in the actual data when I use the textstat_frequency command “Australia” occurs 1716 times, n-grams “this country = 526 times and “our country”  = 91 times.  This total 2333.  “Australia Post” occurs 145 times.
When I run the same code to count phrases, “aus” is recorded as occurring 2333 times and “australia post” 145 times.  It would seem that the 145 times “Australia” is included in ”Australia post” is still being counted , under “aus”. I believe the total should be 2188.
I can’t work out why the cde works on the dummy data and not on the actual data. Any advice is appreciated.

If I understand the issue correctly, that when you call 'convert', the totals are representative of the counts for each? If so, aus accounts for both Australia and Australia Post in the dummy data, as well.  Perhaps we have different versions of quanteda?

Thanks Kat. I'm using V3.3.1.  After looking at the output yet again, it is clearer what I want, which is to count a word only once, which would be a hybrid of the two counts. For example, if Australia is in Australia Post,  Australia = 2 (as in the phrase count) not 3 (as in the key count). However, dairy would = 3, as in the key count.  I treated the  dictionary as a hierarchy (Australia as in Australia Post would have been counted before Australia was encountered in the dictionary), but it doesn't seem to be.

Lookup functions such as tokens_lookup() and kwic() will (by default) match each value of the dictionary to each occurrence found. That means that if a value (e.g., "Australia") occurs both within a phrase and on its own in more than one dictionary keys, it will be once for the compound (e.g., Australia Post") and once for the individual match. You can control this behaviour in for instance tokens_lookup() using nested scope = "dictionary" but it will still replace the values with keys. This functionality does not exist in kwic().
So how about a different way of counting your frequencies, using compounding to control that is nested? Here's how:
> tokens_compound(x, dict, concatenator = " ") |>
    dfm() |>
    t() |>
    print(-1, -1)

Document-feature matrix of: 24 documents, 4 features (63.54% sparse) and 0 docvars.
                features
docs             doc1 doc2 doc3 doc4
  there             1    0    0    0
  are               1    0    2    1
  a                 1    1    0    1
  lot               1    0    0    0
  of                1    1    0    0
  dairy farms       1    0    1    0
  in                1    1    1    0
  australia         1    1    0    0
  dairy             0    1    0    0
  comprise          0    1    0    0
  significant       0    1    0    0
  percent           0    1    0    0
  all               0    1    1    0
  farms             0    1    2    0
  not               0    0    2    0
  fact              0    0    1    0
  most              0    0    1    0
  some              0    0    0    1
  lucky             0    0    0    1
  to                0    0    0    1
  receive           0    0    0    1
  service           0    0    0    1
  from              0    0    0    1
  australia post    0    0    0    1

Here, the "Australia" in "Australia Post" is not counted as "Australia".

Thanks Ken.  I planned to respecifiy my question but you beat me to it. Yours is an interesting approach but with 700 documents extracting what I want would be difficult. There used to be a program called VBPro that allowed you to substitute words for a dictionary key code, then you could count the codes. I essentially want to do something similar - count frequency and number of documents for all words with the dairy key; count australia post frequency/documents, australia excluding australia post etc. My dictionary has 40 keys (some just words, some phrases and some both words and phrases).

I think you should respecify the question with a smaller example that represents the larger problem, and specify exactly the output you are looking for. Then I can reformulate the solution.

Apologies for not being able to format this properly. I think I may have found a workaround. First run
code.
tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farms"), concatenator = " ") %>%
tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farm"), concatenator = " ") %>%
tokens_compound(phrase("australia post"), concatenator = " ")                               code.
then run a kwic analysis of the dictionary and extract the "pattern" column ;   table (x2)
x2
aus auspost   dairy farmers
2       1       3       3

In essence, I want to count frequency and number of documents for words/phrases as they are contained in a dictionary key. Your nested example,
counted Australia and Australia Post correctly, but the contents of the dairy key were counted separately as dairy and dairy farms
(in the output they should be 1 row not two). I'm only interested in the word/phrases in the dictionary as a key.

FTo check I'm on the right track, I'll respecify in a new question, which I can better format .
